# How to prove divergence of $\sum_{p \text{ prime}} \frac 1 p$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, divergent-series

I want to prove that $$\sum_{p \text{ prime}} \frac 1 p$$ diverges. I checked the wikipedia page about that: [Divergence of the sum of the reciprocals of the primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes), but I wanted something simple. So I just used the fact that the next prime is always greater than the last one to show that: $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| > 1,$ where $a_n$ is $1$ over the $n$-th prime, so the sum must diverge. But I am not sure this is ok, can anybody tell me?

Comment: Your argument does not make sense.  The $n^{th}$ term is the reciprocal of the $n^{th}$ prime, so the terms definitely decrease to $0$.

Comment: The proof by Erdos, described in the article you link to, is quite elementary (though not exactly easy).  Worth studying.

Comment: For a number of different proofs, as well as a discussion of many related topics, see Julian Havil's book "Gamma: Exploring Euler's constant". I thought the first chapter was weak and somewhat confusing, but the rest is fascinating.

Comment: The ratio test would say $\dfrac{1/p_{n+1}}{1/p_n} = \dfrac{p_n}{p_{n+1}} <1.$ But that doesn't mean the LIMIT is less than $1:$ a sequence of numbers less than $1$ can approach $1$ as the limit. $\qquad$

Answer (score 4):

The answer is NO:

Let $a_n= \frac{1}{p_n}$, $p_n < p_{n+1}$
Then actually $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| < 1$

Answer (score 1):

Actually $$\left|\frac{1/p_{n+1}}{1/p_{n}}\right|<1$$

In the limit, all you get that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{1/p_{n+1}}{1/p_{n}}\right|\le 1 $$

So even if your inequality WAS true, it wouldn't be enough to prove divergence.

Answer (score 0):

The sum diverges, but very very slow.

Take the reciprocals of the integers from $2^k$ to $2^{k+1}$: They are between $2^{-(k+1)}$ and $2^{-k}$, and there are $2^k$ of them, so their sum is between 1/2 and 1. If we add the reciprocals from 1 to $2^k$, then we have about k such sums, so the total is between k/2 and k; the sum up to some m is actually about $\ln m$.

Now we only add the reciprocals of primes. A random number p is prime with probability about 1 / ln p. So the sum of reciprocals *of primes* in the interval between $2^{-(k+1)}$ and $2^{-k}$ is only about $1 / k$. And adding this from 1 to $2^k$ is the sum of 1/k from 1 to k or about $\ln k$. And the sum of reciprocals of primes from 1 to m is about $\ln \ln m$.

So this diverges very, very slowly.

On the positive side, you just need to take all this and turn it into a real proof. You know the limit of (primes <= n * ln n / n) is 1, that needs to be turned into a lower bound for primes in an interval.